# Selecting columns as rows

Tags: sql

Query:

```
SELECT 'SUMS' AS [Desc], SUM(PriceN) AS Nett, SUM(PriceG) AS Gross 
FROM Resources
```

gives me a resultset:

```
Desc     Nett   Gross  
-------- ----   ------   
SUMS     515.00 621.55
```

I need a resultset which looks like this:

```
Desc   Value  
----   -----  
Nett   515.00  
Gross  621.55
```

I was struggling with pivot statement, but unfortunately I cannot make it to work.
This is only part of the problem, because I have to be able to add more sums to select statement.
I'm looking for any clue, how to deal with this problem. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
SELECT 'Nett' AS [Desc], SUM(PriceN) AS Value FROM Resources
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Gross' AS [Desc], SUM(PriceG) AS Value FROM Resources
```

Comment: Thx... simplicity is power! :D